# Sqlite query in Android for auto increment and default values

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I want to be able to add data in sqlite using android. 
The column Id should have primary key and should be an auto increment field.
And status should have a default value of 0. Wasn't sure if this is the way to do it for sqlite.

```
public static  final String DATABASE_NAME="tododata";       
public static  final String TABLE_NAME="todolist";       
public static  final int KEY_ID= 0;               
public static  final String KEY_TITLE="Title";                 
public static final String KEY_DESCRIPTION="Description";
// public static final Date KEY_DATE = ;
public static final int KEY_STATUS = 0;

public static  final int DATABASE_VERSON=1;           

public DataHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSON);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table "+TABLE_NAME+"(Id integer primary key not null autoincrement 1 , title text not null, description text not null, date date not null, status int default 0);");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("drop table if exists "+TABLE_NAME);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be the correct syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, title TEXT NOT NULL, description TEXT NOT NULL, date DATE NOT NULL, status INTEGER DEFAULT 0)
```

Comment: How to set auto increment initial value? @MatPag

Comment: The initial value of an integer autoincrement is always 0, it is automatically setup by SQLITE and should not be handled by you

Comment: What do i write in the 6 th line (commented) for the value of Date? @MatPag

Comment: If you follow the official Android tutorial here: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html it will be more easy to understand everything

Comment: @MatPag The initial value will be 1 not 0 as per *If the table is initially empty, then a ROWID of 1 is used.* *The AUTOINCREMENT keyword imposes extra CPU, memory, disk space, and disk I/O overhead and should be avoided if not strictly needed.* i.e. unless you need it best to not use it. Also you can handle the index and set it's value e.g. you may wish to start keys from a specfific number. Quotes are from [SQLite Autoincrement](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html)

Comment: @MikeT Sorry, you are perfectly right on the initial value of the autoincrement keyword, i were convinced it started from 0 and not from 1 :D. Performances are not a problem on Android if you have a human amount of tables and the autoincrement should be used everytime it makes sense. Starting an autoincrement from a specific value should be avoided because it breaks the real scope of the autoincrement option.

Comment: @MatPag  All AUTOINCREMENT offers, over not coding it (where it could be coded), is that it guarantees that the id/key will not be a previously used, but deleted id/key and increasing, but NOT necessarily sequentially, until the max ROWID value is reached. I can't see why it makes sense to be used everytime when the official SQLitedocumentation says the opposite. I'd also appreciate what you meany by  *the real scope of AUTOINCREMENT option*,

Comment: @MikeT The official SQLite documentation is old (or not categorized enough). Current android devices have no problems to handle dozens of autoincrement tables. [This](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/provider/ScheduleDatabase.java#L226-L435) is the current Google IO app, as you can see they used autoincrement in pretty every table even if it is not fundamental to the app logic. Using it it's strongly encouraged by everyone except the SQLite documentation...

Comment: @MatPag  So I for one am a nobody by your statement, thankyou. Alternately your statement, that *everyone ...*, is false. With the exception of yourself, I have not come across any single instance of the advice of not using AUTOINCREMENT being disputed as being bad or not the best practice. I'm sure you can enlighten me with links to all of these occurrences of ***everyone(sic) strongly encouraging to use AUTOINCREMENT***.

Answer (score 0):

Your Query should be like in this format :-

```
sqliteDatabase.execSQL("create table tableName ("+COL1_NAME+" integer primary key  autoincrement, "+COL2_NAME+" text , "+COL3_NAME+" text , "+COL4_NAME+" text)");
```